# GPS creating a route to destination

Tags: ios, objective-c, routes, gps, direction

I'm working in version 4.6.2 of xcode, and my goal is to display the shortest/quickest route to a destination you searched for.

I've looked all over the internet and stackoverflow and i found alot of things but i can't figure it out on how to implement it in my application.

I started with a "Single View Application Project"
At the moment i have a world map with 4 buttons and a search bar:

"Location" - Which brings you to your current location.
"Normal" - Shows the default map.
"Satellite" - Shows the satellite map.
"Hybrid" - Shows the hybrid map.
http://tinypic.com/r/15g8m87/5

And this is the current code i have to control it.

"ViewController.h"

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController { 

IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

}

 -(IBAction)findmylocation:(id)sender;<br>
 -(IBAction)setmaptype:(id)sender;

@end
```

And "ViewController.m"

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController;

-(IBAction)findmylocation:(id)sender {

    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    mapView.delegate = self;
    [mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES];


}

-(IBAction)setmaptype:(id)sender {

    switch (((UISegmentedControl *)sender).selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
            break;
        case 1:
            mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
            break;
        case 2:
            mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
            break;

        default:
            mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
            break;
    }

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with Apple maps, you would need the route as sequence of coordibates. Neither apple nor google provide this Api. you only can get a route based on OpenstreetMaps, but this will often not fit perfectly to the apple map.
so you also have to change to an OpenstreetMap based view, like MapKit.

Comment: Is there a site or something where they explain how to make a map with directions because i'm stuck.

Comment: Look, at RouteMe Project (Open Source Library)

Comment: Thanks, But now i'm all the way at the beginning again, I looked at it and followed a list of instructions and still have nothing not even a map, (Sorry if i'm being annoying it's just that i have been trying for multiple days now, and frustration is kicking in.)

Comment: this topic is more suited for advanced sw developper.